# Is there any definitive documentation on the ontology of Windows Runtime (WinRT)?

Tags: windows-runtime

Is there any definitive documentation on the ontology of Windows Runtime (WinRT)?

My primary concern is not the individual functions, but the overall architecture with respect too 'whats in' and 'whats out' and some notes on categorization.

Comment: I'm having a hard time envisioning what you are looking for.  A visual representation of the class hierarchy?

Comment: i guess a Blog from MS explaining how/why they chose/grouped features into RT.  its a different Fx that .NET with vague namespaces like 'Windows.ApplicationModel', 'Windows.Foundation' and 'Windows.Internal'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Knowledge is in O'Reilly cookbooks. I don't think o'reilly cares about m$ very much.

Answer (score 0):

On the technical side WinRT uses the same metadata format as .NET, on the non-technical side (i.e. conventions) it looks like they reused many of the API and Framework conventions from .NET (except of course keeping the COM-based rules, so ignoring stuff like "don't do your own reference counting").

Here is the definitive book on the .NET Framework (3.0/3.5/4.0) naming conventions, rules, and API design guidelines.

[http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Development/dp/0321545613](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)

You don't mention your platform (WinJS/.NET/C++/...).  If your focus is native or WinJS I would suggest borrowing but not buying this book, as I would expect them to release a new one for WinRT.  (Just speaking on my experience, here, this book is usually updated for each major release of .NET .)

Lastly, I posted a question on the book author's blog, asking if he was still the 'internal maintainer' of these design guidelines.  [The comment was on the blog post for his BUILD video.  My comment isn't showing right now, but I hope it will later, so including the link.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2011/09/20/10214468.aspx)